# multiple calls while acitivity is still open

Tags: android

I have a counter in my activity that needs to be updated when the value in my api changes.
I would like to call the request every 5 seconds to check if my api value has changed, to update the counter, while the acitivity is open.

I don't know of any method that will allow me to make these requests over time.

My methods in Kotlin

```
   private fun getTotalTrees() {
        disposable = viewModel.getTotalTrees().subscribeBy(
            onNext = {
                totalTrees = it
            },
            onError = {
                Timber.e(it)
            },
            onComplete = {
                setAnimator()
            }
        )
    }

    private fun setAnimator() {
        root.tv_contador
            .setInterpolator(AccelerateInterpolator())
            .countAnimation(lastTotalTrees, totalTrees)
    }
```

I'd like a way to call the `getTotalTrees()` method every 5 seconds.
But it also needs a way to terminate this function when my activity ends.
That is, in the onStop method
Can someone help me?

[EDIT]

I solved

```
    override fun getTotalTrees(): Flowable<Int> {
        return Flowable.just(10320) // here goes the api call 
            .repeat() // here is the magic
            .delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // delay in repeat
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

    }
```

Comment: Try with Timer.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: try `Observable.interval`

Answer (score 0):

You can try CountdownTimer, re-call start when the timer has finished

```
new CountDownTimer(5000, 5000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            start();
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: This does not help to execute the method while the activity is open. There is no way to know how long the activity will be active before onStop

Comment: Assign CountDownTimer instance to an activity variable ("timer", for ex.) and on onStop event, just call timer.cancel()